# Orthogonal transformation stays orthogonal if we change the inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $(E,\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle)$ be a finite euclidian space and let $f$ be an orthogonal linear transformation defined on it. Does $f$ stays orthogonal if we change the underlying inner product of $E$? If this is not true in general, what are the conditions that we can impose on $f$ to make it true?

Comment: Of course not. Take a rotation of $\mathbb R^2$. It preserves the usual inner product, but does it preserve, say, $\langle (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)\rangle = x_1x_2+2y_1y_2?$

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general, because orthogonality is a condition that depends on the inner product choice. Requiring that a map preserves every possible inner product is equivalent to requiring that there is a matrix $B$ such that:
$$(Bx)^TA(By)=x^TAy$$
for every positive definite matrix $A$. This implies that:
$$B^TAB=A$$
For $A=I_n$ we have that $B^T=B^{-1}$, so:
$$B^{-1}AB=A$$
So:
$$AB=BA$$
for every positive definite matrix $A$. I think (NOT SURE THOUGH) that this should be enough to say that $B=\lambda I_n$ for some $\lambda$. But since:
$$B^TAB=A$$
we have:
$$\lambda^2A=A$$
i.e. $\lambda=\pm 1$ and $B=\pm I_n$.

Comment: That's a nice question you have there (the NOT SURE THOUGH). The standard tool to prove that a matrix that commutes with all matrices in a given class is a scalar is Schur's lemma of representation theory. I wonder whether you can apply it here. May be worth opening another question on this website.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would actually say that we can conclude that B has only ±1 on the diagonal, not that it's exactly ±I.